# Find element by xpath in selenium takes more time when NoSuchElementException encounters

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm using selenium to gather information from web page.There are two kinds of webpage, one needs pushing the button to show the information needed and another one show the information directly.

```
try:
    BrowserObj_dirver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@id='tab-item-relationships']/a").click()
    test=BrowserObj_dirver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='enum']/a")
    for t in test:
        if t.text not in sha256:
            sql2="insert into sha2 values (%d,'%s')" % (virusId,t.text)
            sha256.append(t.text)
            cursor.execute(sql2)
            db.commit()
            virusId=virusId+1
            print t.text
except NoSuchElementException:
    print "no button"
    (and operation for no button page here)
```

But it take much more time when NoSuchElementException encounters,usually 7s -10s.What's the reason?

Comment: Try setting the implicit wait time to a value you want, like BrowserObj_dirver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. I thought that implicitly_wait only works for next search only before, but actually it effects everyvsearch afterward.Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear. Added this info as a full reply - if you accept the answer, the question won't remain open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the implicit wait time to a value you want, like `BrowserObj_dirver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds`

This will work for every findElement the driver will execute from this point onward. Of course, if you set the waiting time very low, findElement might not wait for elements that are still loading.

Alternatively, you can use a variant of WebDriverWait, see this documentation for starters: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html